# Clipping one shapefile file with 100 different shapefiles (Arcmap 10.1) and retrive 100 diferent outputs using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iteration

I have tried without success to perform this task with ArcMap 10.1. I´m struggling with ModelBuilder.

I have one shapefile (mean precipitation in one country) and I need to clip this shapefile with 100 different shapefiles (watershed areas). I can´t use Union to create a single shapefile from the 100 different shapefiles, because some of them overlap.

Can this kind of task can be automated with Iterate Feature Classes inside ModelBuilder and, if so, where can I find an example?

Comment: If your true goal is precipitation per catchment you need intersect, no need to iterate.  After you need to calculate weighted of rain averaged by area for each catchment. It will work with overlapping catchment.

Comment: Yes my true goal is precipitation per catchment. Thank you. I will also try intersect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:
[image]

For your Clip Output name you will need to use [inline variable substitution](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/inline-variable-substitution.htm) in order to create a separate output file for your 100 shapefiles. Use %Name% should do the trick.

[image]

I recommend trying this on a small subset of your data say 3 polygons to see how it works.